# Error during instalation of mysql module in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to install mysql module for node.js via npm.

I use next command:

```
$npm install -d mysql
```

and here is stacktrace:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm info install mysql@2.0.0-alpha5 into C:\Users\Yoshi
npm info installOne mysql@2.0.0-alpha5
npm info C:\Users\Yoshi\node_modules\mysql unbuild
npm info preinstall mysql@2.0.0-alpha5
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 13:22:30
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
npm info install require-all@0.0.3 into C:\Users\Yoshi\node_modules\mysql
npm info installOne require-all@0.0.3
npm info C:\Users\Yoshi\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\require-all unbuild
npm info C:\Users\Yoshi\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\require-all unbuild
npm info C:\Users\Yoshi\node_modules\mysql unbuild
npm info preuninstall mysql@2.0.0-alpha5
npm info uninstall mysql@2.0.0-alpha5
npm info postuninstall mysql@2.0.0-alpha5
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Yoshi\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\require-all\package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
 "-d" "mysql"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yoshi\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.9.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.70
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Yoshi\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\require-all\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yoshi\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Can you tell me what's wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I got the same errors... Hope someone could figure it out...

Comment: try again after `npm cache clean`